# SQL2000 & 2005 user access

Tags: sql-server

How can I kill/block user access to our 2000 & 2005 SQL database for a set timeframe? We don't have permission to kill spids. The goal is to stop the user from blocking jobs that are scheduled to run overnight.  FYI-the user is updating Crystal Reports 8 & XI.

Answer (score 0):

- First revoke the users permission to run queries. (If they are all member of a role, this is quite easy and quick.) More brute force is completely denying connect.

  ```
  DENY CONNECT SQL TO [youruser]
  ```
- Second switch your database to single user with rollback and switch it back to multi user. (if you have rights for that, otherwise you have to wait until the user disconnects.)

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE xxx SET SINGLE_USER
  WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
  GO
  ALTER DATABASE xxx SET MULTI_USER
  ```

Comment: If you don't kill the spids there will always be somebody that creates a linked table in MsAccess and leaves it open when he goes home. (and this creates an exclusive table lock)

Comment: Agreed but the OP specifically says they can't do this. Not really sure what they **do** want to happen.